# Cuando javascript no encuentra un elemento en el dom no continua

Tags: javascript

cómo están ?
Estoy empezando con javascript, y ahora me acaba de surgir un problema el cual no doy con la solución en google.

Tengo un archivo único de javascript para (por el momento) 5 archivos html ...
Es que cuando no encuentra el/los elementos que no están en ese HTML y me corta el código
(yo creí que era como CSS que ignora lo que no encuentra).

Sí, el llamado a javascript está abajo de todo dentro del body.

Cómo puedo solucionar esto?
Ya que creando un javascript para cada página no es lógico.
Existe solución ?

Agradezco cualquier ayuda o sugerencia.
Aunque repito, recién comienzo.

Saludos!!
Mika.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres hacer un js para TODOS, lo primero que he de decirte, es que no es optimo. Pero estás empezando, ya irás aprendiendo truquillos (yo sigo aprendiendo, pero lo poco que se, te servirá).

Si hay un elemento que no existe en determinado html haz esto:

```
if(elemento){...codigo...}
else{...codigo...}
```

Esto hace que, si el elemento existe, ejecute X código, sino (else) ejecute otro. O bien puedes suprimir el else y seguir naturalmente.

O bien, con un:

```
if(!elemento){...}
else{...}
```

Con el ! haces una negativa, si el elemento NO existe, ejecuta X código, sino (si existe) ejecuta Y.

Comment: muchísimas gracias por el comentario !  sé que no es bueno poner todo junto, pero recién me estoy organizando . Te hago una última pregunta . si yo pongo if(elemento){ código } else { } ... ahora else lo tengo vacío y funciona perfecto.. pero debo dejarlo vacío ?

Comment: Irrelevante. Las condiciones if / else son para controlar flujos y su uso puede ser variado dependiendo de los casos prácticos. Voy a editar ka respuesta de AQMR para extender esta idea.

Comment: @Deneuve01 si el else está vacío, yo lo quitaría, si. Ahora te digo, puede haber muchas opciones mejores a la que yo te planteo,

Answer (score 1):

Yo te recomiendo utilizar la programación orientada a objetos: crea tu propia librería que resuelve problemas, déjala global en tu página y luego, desde cada HTML, llama los métodos que necesites.

Igualmente, te aconsejo programar de forma dinámica para que puedas reutilizar código:

```javascript
// malo
function EliminaTituloDOM(){
  document.querySelector('h1').remove()
}
EliminaTituloDOM()

// mejor
function EliminaDelDOM(id){
  document.querySelector(id).remove();
}
EliminaDelDOM('id-del-h1');

// óptimo: código aislado, escalable y relativo
lib = {
  eliminaPorID: id => document.querySelector(id).remove(),
  eliminaPorClass: clase => document.querySelectorAll(clase).forEach(del => el.remove()),
}

lib.eliminaPorID('id-del-elemento');
lib.eliminaPorClass('classe-de-muchos');
```